# Beego NewLogger channelLens value

Tags: go, logging, beego

Can someone help me understand the significance of `channelLens` value in [Beego NewLogger](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/astaxie/beego/logs#NewLogger) function. The documentation says `channelLen means the number of messages in chan(used where asynchronous is true). if the buffering chan is full, logger adapters write to file or other way.` & Its not clear for me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you pass no parameter to NewLogger() it uses defaultAsyncMsgLen as internal channel size. This line: https://github.com/astaxie/beego/blob/v1.12.3/logs/log.go#L151

When you pass a parameter the logger uses it as internal channel size.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I already understood the point you shared in the documentation. 
What I meant by my question is what is the impact of the channelLens value? memory-wise & performance-wise? How can I (or a dev) decide which value to give here?

Comment: channelLens value depends on your use case. This logger has single goroutine file writer. For example, http server has N goroutines and each writes 2 messages. Then chanlen should be more than N*2 to prevent delaying the clients while logger does long term operations like file rotation. If logger has smtpoutput default value is probably ok, since logger will block goroutines anyway because smtp sending is slow.

Comment: consumed memory should be channelLens*12*average_logmsg_len bytes. (12 is empty string size)